# make an option from a selection tag do action on the whole site PHP

Tags: php, html

iamiI have a selection tag and and options that can do task in the page , but the problem is that it just does that in just the index page and not and the others... this is my code:

region.php

```
   (isset($_POST["company"])) ? $company = $_POST["company"] : $company=1;

    if(isset($_POST['selectedRegion'])){

        $region =  explode( "|" ,$_POST['selectedRegion']) ;

        $_SESSION['regCode'] = $region[0];

        $_SESSION['selection'] = $region[1];
        $regionCode = $_SESSION['regCode'];



    }else if(isset($_SESSION['regCode'])){

        $region[1] = $_SESSION['selection'];

       $regionCode =  $_SESSION['regCode'] ;

    }else{

    $regionCode = 'DEF';
    $_SESSION['regCode'] = $regionCode;


    }


<form id="regionSelect" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
        <select id="selectedRegion" name="selectedRegion" size="1" autocomplete="off">
            <option style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #000" value="<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['regCode']) and $_SESSION['regCode'] != 'DEF'){ echo "".$_POST['selectedRegion']."";}?>" selected="selected"><?php if (isset($_SESSION['regCode']) and $_SESSION['regCode'] != "DEF"){ echo "".$region[1]."";}else{echo "--------";} ?></option>  
            <option value="ny">New York</option>
            <option value="miami">Miami</option>
        </select>  
        <input type="submit" value="Enter Region" />
 </form>
```

process.php

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION)){ session_start();}

    if(isset($_POST['selectedRegion'])){

   $region = $_SESSION['selectedRegion']=$_POST['selectedRegion']; 

    if($region == "ny"){

    echo "new york selected";

    }

    if($region == "miami"){
    echo "miami selected";
     }
```

?>

The index.php and all the other pages of the site have the region.php and the process.php included, but my problem is that any time that i do a selection it just does the action on the page that is in... and if i want the action to be made in another page i would have to press the option again. is there anyway that i can do the action of my selection work on page change and all the pages of my site? thanks

Comment: You are probably looking for the term "php session variable". Google for that. An alternative would be to set a cookie on the client side. Comes out the same. A session variable is easier to implement.

Comment: i will try that , i saw so many pages that can change their whole site with a selection

Comment: Yes sure, certainly you will change your choice only once, for example on the start page. The session varaible allows you to store that value on the serverside and reuse the decision for each subsequent request the same client sends afterwards. Think of it as glueing together otherwise separate requests.

Comment: have u found that on google? please send me the link of an example

Comment: I tried to express things more clear in an answer I posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you are looking for consists of these steps:

1. you evaluate the selection you receive at session start from the client, according to what the user has chosen. So just what you have so far.
2. you store that selection in a session variable. See [the php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) for the basic use of a session variable. It just boils down to:

   ```
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['region'] = $_POST['selectedRegion'];
   ```
3. you create a switch statement based on that session variable in *all* scripts that should react on that user choice:

   ```
   session_start();
   switch ($_SESSION['region']) {
       case 'ny': 
           // do something
           break;
       case 'miami': 
           // do something
           break;
       default: 
           // do something
   }
   ```

With this the user has to make his choice only once inside a single session (returning requests). You can offer that selection on the entry page and/or on all pages, just as you like. You can enhance that by storing that inside a persistent user profile, if you have an account management.

---

In addition some more information, as a reaction to your additional information as you provided by editing your question.

Your general approach is probably into the right direction, great. There are a few issues you have to correct though. I can only hint to them, since you offer only snippets of your scripts.

1. In 'process.php' you have this line:

   ```
   $region = $_SESSION['selectedRegion']=$_POST['selectedRegion'];
   ```

This is obviously invalid syntax, you cannot have *two* assignments inside a single statement. At least that does not do what you want it to.

1. not sure if this conditional really belongs there:

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['selectedRegion']))
   ```

It is fine *if* 'process.php' is the script meant to SET the session variable. In all other scripts obviously `$_POST['selectedRegion']` is not set, since the user did not make a choice / was not offered a choice. So there you cannot test or use that variable, you just use the session variable directly.

1. there are a few other things, but as said you are on the right track.

This approach *does* work, it is the "normal" approach to this. So don't get frustrated, you will sort this out. In general: your code is a little confusing, too many separate variables where it is unclear what purpose they save. Why the distinction between `region`, `regionCode` and `selectedRegion`. Why isn't a single variable sufficient? Try to simplify your code, this will help to get this to work.

Comment: I have no users management, the switch code works but again its just doing it in one page, so when ever i click another link the action is gone :SS

Comment: You do set that session variable and it is lost in the next request? Please post that new code by editing your question above and appending a section where you copy the relevant lines from 1. the script with the session variable being written and 2. some other script where you try to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) ..thats how i have it right now look up

Comment: I added a few details, hope that helps. I cannot post read-to-use code, since I see only snippets of your scripts. But you head into the right direction. I am confident you will tackle this down :-)

Answer (score 0):

Value of `$_POST['selectedRegion']` will not be available always. You should store this value in session like `$_SESSION['selectedReg']=$_POST['selectedRegion'];`  during the form  submission.

```
<form id="regionSelect" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
        <option style="border-bottom: 1px dashed #000" value="<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['regCode']) and $_SESSION['regCode'] != 'DEF'){ echo $_SESSION['selectedRegion'];}?>" ><?php if (isset($_SESSION['regCode']) and $_SESSION['regCode'] != "DEF"){ echo $_SESSION['selectedRegion'];}else{echo "--------";} ?></option>  
            <option value="ny">New York</option>
            <option value="miami">Miami</option>
        </select>  
        <input type="submit" value="Enter Region" />
 </form>
```

Comment: i tried that but i get this :(
A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Comment: Do you know `header` function?

Comment: Do you want to send the user on other page on the basis of submitted value? if yes then you should use `header('location:abc.php');` to redirect to `abc.php` page from your php code.

Comment: not really redirect them, just want to do whatever the action from option was on all the pages of the site